# submit on checkbox input depending on confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have multiple rows, where each row is a form with a a checkbox. Im trying to sumbmit the form depending on some data regarding the id of the object mapped in the row.

every form looks like this:

```
<?php foreach ($tables as $table): ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $table->get_id(); ?></td>
       <form method="POST" action="/kviberg/admin/sparabord">
         <input type="hidden" name="table_id" value="<?php echo $table->get_id(); ?>">
         <td>
           <span style="display: none;">
             <?php if($table->get_available() == 1) echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; ?>
           </span>
           <input onclick="confirm_unavailable_table(this.form);" type="checkbox" name="available" value="<?php echo $table->get_available(); ?>" <?php if($table->get_available() == 1) echo "checked"; ?>>
         </td>
       </form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the function:

```
function confirm_unavailable_table(form) {
   event.preventDefault();         <--- ERROR
   var id = form.table_id.value;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     url: "/kviberg/views/ajax_check_availability.php", 
     data: {id : id},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
        if(data.res_id > 0) {
          if(confirm("There are no reservations (reservations id: " + data.res_id + ").\nDo you want to continue?"));
            form.submit();
          }
        }
        else if(data.sub_id > 0) {
          if(confirm("There are subscriptions (prenumerations id: " + data.sub_id + ").\nDo you want to continue?")) {
            form.submit();
          }
        }
        else if(data.sub_id == 0 && data.res_id == 0) {
          form.submit();
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("error on data");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Right now the form never submits through the ajax call. Does it have to do with asynchronous behaviour?

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Have you confirmed that `data` is what you expect to be?

Comment: Yes I have, the page reloads but the checkbox, stays check/or unchecked

Comment: So the form submits, it does not change any value because of `event.preventDefault();` that prevents checkbox to change checked state.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks, you saved my day. Post it as a answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form submits, it does not change any value because of `event.preventDefault();` - that prevents checkbox from changing checked state.